# DontDestroyOnLoad - how to destroy?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm working on a **Vuforia** (legacy) application.

In "Play" mode in Unity I can see that some **"DontDestroyOnLoad" content is being generated**, (looks like it's sort of a camera).

[image]

This might be a reason of why I have some problems when switching between the scenes, so the question is **how to make these elements "destroyable"**?

Comment: Probably duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425830/how-to-destroy-a-game-object-marked-dontdestroyonload-when-a-new-scene-loads

Answer (score 0):

'DontDestroyOnLoad' It means that they won't manage it automatically. so if you want to destroy it, you should destroy manually like

GameObject.Destroy(GameObject.Find("TextureBufferCamera"));